# decode h264 video in iphone

Tags: ios, decode, h.264, decoding

I have video in my library . I have compress that video using h264 codec . now I want that video to be decoded in the normal video by that mean it should be decoded in the mode that I want . can anyone tell me how to do that?

p.s. I am doing it in ios .

Answer (score 1):

I also do a similar function, I use **ffmpeg library decoding**, there are many examples online, but the library ios on the decoding delay of about 0.3 seconds, if we can tolerate such a delay you can use this library under the hood

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't know how to compile ffmpeg library for iOS.

Comment: I am using of xcode Version 3.2.5, ios-4.2.  Edit the library method:
Compiled arm6:
_./configure --enable-cross-compile --arch=c --target-os=darwin --cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk --cpu=arm6 --extra-cflags='-arch armv7' --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7' --libdir=/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_arm7 --prefix=/ffmpeg/prefix_arm7 --disable-asm_

Comment: Compile i386
_./configure --cpu=i386 --enable-cross-compile --target-os=darwin --arch=c --prefix=/ffmpeg/prefix_i386 --libdir=/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_i386 --cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 --enable-zlib --enable-bzlib --disable-armv6 --extra-libs=-lpthread --enable-shared --enable-memalign-hack_

Comment: Compilation step:
_(1) the cd the ffmpeg.
(2) enter the configure above configuration
3. The make
4 make install
Generated static library / the ffmpeg / static library copy or connection under the project, copy the header files or connect to the project
Header Search Paths =. / FFMPEG_LIB / include
(6) to generate the other versions, you need to make clean
If there are compilation errors, repeat the above operation, recompile
_
Description: When editing the app, use a different static library